# R - Read binary matrix with no separator

Tags: r, binary-data

I am trying to read a large (~100mb) binary matrix in R. This is how the plaintext looks like:

```
10001010
10010100
00101101
```

Expected output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
r1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
r2  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
r3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

I am currently reading each line and separating the bits. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to separate it?  Perhaps `strsplit("10001010", "")[[1]]`

Comment: I want a matrix or data frame, with each element containing 1 bit.

Comment: Please show the expected output by updating your post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option (which could be slow) would be to `scan` the `.txt` file, `split` the elements by the delimiter `""`, convert to `numeric/integer` and `rbind` the `list` elements to create a `matrix`.

```
 m1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(scan("inpfile.txt", 
                 what=""), ""), as.numeric))
 m1
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 #[1,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
 #[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
 #[3,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
```

A slightly more faster version is reading the file with `fread`, then use `tstrsplit`

```
library(data.table)
fread("inpfile.txt", colClasses="character")[, tstrsplit(V1, "")]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#1:  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
#2:  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
#3:  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

I would also change the delimiter by creating space between each character using `awk` (if the OP is using `linux`) and then read with `fread` (I can't test it as I am on a `windows` system.)

---

A faster option may also include using `library(iotools)`

```
n <- nchar(scan(file, what="",n=1))
library(iotools)
input.file("inpfile.txt", formatter=dstrfw, 
           col_types=rep("integer",n), widths=rep(1,n))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
#2  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
#3  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

#### Benchmarks

Using a slightly bigger dataset, the timings between `readr` and `iotools` are below.

```
n <-100000
cat(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{8})", "\\1\n", paste(sample(0:1, 
                n*8, TRUE), collapse="")), 
              file="dat2.txt")
library(readr)
tic <- Sys.time()
read_fwf("dat2.txt", fwf_widths(rep(1, 8)))
difftime(Sys.time(), tic)
#Time difference of 1.142145 secs

tic <- Sys.time()
input.file("dat2.txt", formatter=dstrfw, 
  col_types=rep("integer",8), widths=rep(1,8))
difftime(Sys.time(), tic)
#Time difference of 0.7440939 secs

library(LaF)
tic <- Sys.time()
laf <- laf_open_fwf("dat2.txt", column_widths = rep(1, 
    8),  column_types=rep("integer", 8))
## further processing (larger in memory)
dat <- laf[,]
difftime(Sys.time(), tic)
#Time difference of 0.1285172 secs
```

The most efficient so far is `library(LaF)` posted by @Tyler Rinker, followed by `library(iotools)`

Comment: If I read all the lines first (using read.table), and then separate the bits using strsplit, operations over the matrix are much faster (~3X) as compared to your solution.

Comment: @ShubhamSaini I havent' checked the timings.  But `fread` from `data.table` would be faster than `read.table`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that is also taking me a lot of time (strsplit is a slow function perhaps).

Comment: I am working with large matrices that have hundreds of thousands of columns. strsplit takes a lot of time.

Comment: @ShubhamSaini Can you try with `iotools` (just updated)

Comment: I had also used the LaF package which I think is comparable to iotools.  Hadn't heard of iotools.  +1

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks , I also gave you +1.  I noticed the `LaF` update.  I will include that also in the benchmarks

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(98)`

Answer (score 4):

This might be pretty fast on a large file using **readr**'s fixed width file reader:

```
library(readr)
read_fwf("dat.txt", fwf_widths(rep(1, 8)))

##      X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8
##   (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
## 1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
## 2     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
## 3     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1
```

I wanted to scale up and time.  On the process below it took **readr** ~7.5 seconds to read in a file comparable to the file you discussed.

```
n <-10000000
cat(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{8})", "\\1\n", paste(sample(0:1, n*8, TRUE), collapse="")), file="dat2.txt")

file.size('dat2.txt')  #100000000

tic <- Sys.time()
read_fwf("dat2.txt", fwf_widths(rep(1, 8)))
difftime(Sys.time(), tic)
## Time difference of 7.41096 secs
```

You may also want to consider the LaF package for reading large fixed width files.  Something like:

```
library(LaF)
cols <- 8
laf <- laf_open_fwf("dat2.txt", column_widths = rep(1, cols), 
  column_types=rep("integer", cols))
## further processing (larger in memory)
dat <- laf[,]
```

Comment: I updated the post.  The `LaF` option is the fastest